# Exporting Java application

Tags: java, jar, export

I have a very simple question. How can I export Java program like this Minecraft game is being exported:

[image]

And my bin folder will contain this:

[image]

Is there an any program to do this or any Eclipse plugin? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i didn't downvote but i think this question has been asked several time on stackoverflow.

Comment: Didn't downvote but make sure after you post that your links really do work (you have a preview tab for this).

Comment: @gigadot It was..I know...but it was mostly asked how to export java program to runnable jar. And I don't want to export program's so my customer has to install Java and PostgreSQL manualy, and to make shortcut by his own.

Comment: @giorashc What links? I only have 2 pictures, and they are perfectly displayed.

Comment: @brano88 your customer still have to installer Java and PostgreSQL manually unless you do it in the installer which is not recommended. For database, if you don't want they in install it manually, you should use embedded database.

Comment: I meant the images and on my screen I see this text for both your images : "enter your image description here"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache comes to mind:

1. Apache Ant (for any project): http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html
   Apache Maven - assembly (for Maven projects):
2. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/